# How to send email using AWS IAM role without giving secret key and access key

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-iam

How to send emails using the AWS IAM role without giving secret key and access key using java. Do we have any possibilities for this?

Comment: I think you need to use SES service to send the email, and instead of passing the secret key and access key in the credential file. you need to add IAM role to your ec2 instance where code run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IAM does not involve sending any emails, it is only Identity and Access Management. If you need to send emails, use Amazon SES (Simple Email Service).

When accessing any resource, you must authenticate properly, whether that be with a secret access key or some other way. There is no unauthenticated way to send emails.

Comment: But send mail without using credentials and keys.. Is there any possibilities?